# How to solve this printing problem with css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXhWS.jpg)

When the table exceeds the height of the previous paper, the remaining text will be printed on the next paper in sequence

Among them, the printing scheme cannot be replaced, and the 10th line cannot be changed to the next page

Please provide me with a plan, preferably with an online demo